# Acess denied using Selenium + Heroku

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, heroku

I'm using Selenium to scrape an insurance company's website. Basically, I log in with user credentials to check refund status.

My application normally works locally. When switching to headless Chrome, all I had to do was modify the user-agent, which also worked again.

The problem is when I use Heroku. I keep getting "Access denied", even modifying the user-agent and ensuring that a "headless" user-agent is not being sent.

Here is my code, and the feedback I received:

```
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.binary_location = os.environ.get("GOOGLE_CHROME_BIN")
    options.add_argument("--headless")
    options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
    options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
    options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
    user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/106.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'
    options.add_argument('user-agent={0}'.format(user_agent))

    service = Service(executable_path=os.environ.get("CHROMEDRIVER_PATH"))
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)

    return driver
```

```
2023-07-04T20:29:41.593956+00:00 app[web.1]: <html><head>
2023-07-04T20:29:41.593975+00:00 app[web.1]: <title>Access Denied</title>
2023-07-04T20:29:41.593975+00:00 app[web.1]: </head><body>
2023-07-04T20:29:41.593976+00:00 app[web.1]: <h1>Access Denied</h1>
2023-07-04T20:29:41.593976+00:00 app[web.1]:
2023-07-04T20:29:41.593976+00:00 app[web.1]: You don't have permission to access "http://www.amil.com.br/beneficiario/" on this server.<p>
2023-07-04T20:29:41.593977+00:00 app[web.1]: Reference #18.cd4fde17.1688502581.2beed326
2023-07-04T20:29:41.593977+00:00 app[web.1]:
2023-07-04T20:29:41.593977+00:00 app[web.1]:
2023-07-04T20:29:41.593978+00:00 app[web.1]: </p></body></html>
2023-07-04T20:29:41.598474+00:00 app[web.1]: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/106.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
```

Note that print(driver.execute_script("return navigator.userAgent")) shows a valid user-agent (without Headless), but I'm still receiving acess denied.

Comment: Even accessing manually accessing `http://www.amil.com.br/beneficiario/` I face the same error `You don't have permission to access`

Comment: Are you using some kind of VPN? @undetectedSelenium